# Python selenium scrap data from dynamic website table

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I try to use selenium on python to scrap some information from website https://dexscreener.com/.
Actually, I just want the name of the current upper one in the list (see screenshot). The filters and order of the list is not relevant as I have already implemented this separately.

Using the attachted code structure I tried several methods (By.XPATH, By.Name etc.) but couln’t get the name to print it. I am fairly new to selenium. I use the webdriver for chrome.
Could someone help me with that?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://dexscreener.com/")

table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"...")
print(..)
```

Thanks a lot!!
Best
Maverick

Using the attachted code structure I tried several methods (By.XPATH, By.Name etc.) but couln’t get the name to print it. I am fairly new to selenium.